# 3D Array - Adding Previous 2D Array Values as 3rd Dimension to a New 3D Array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a new 3D array out of an existing 2D array by looping through the existing 2D array, and add all previous rows of the 2D array to the Z axis(depth) of the new 3D array.

I've tried reshaping the existing array to a 3D array, and iterating through the array to append via dstack.

```
my_array = []

my_array_3d = np.reshape(my_array, (my_array.shape[0], 1, my_array.shape[1]))

for idx, val in enumerate(my_array_3d ):
    for i in range(idx):
        np.append(my_array_3d , i, axis=2)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

So if my array looks like this:

```
my_array = ([[1,1,1],
             [2,2,2],
             [3,3,3],
             [4,4,4]])
```

I want the Z[2] to be:

```
[[1,1,1],
[2,2,2]]
```

I want Z[3] to be:

```
[[1,1,1],
 [2,2,2],
 [3,3,3]]
```

Comment: Don't try to use `np.append`.  It does not operate in place (like list append).  And it is hard to get the number of dimensions right, especially when applying it iteratively.

Comment: Re-read your question and I'm not entirely sure if I understood correctly. What do you mean with "index=100 of my 2D array"? Is this the 101. row of your 2D array? Maybe show an example with N=3.

Comment: So for each row in the array, I want to add the previous rows of the array as the 3rd dimension of the array in it's entirety.  So if I'm on row 100, I want rows 0-99 to be the Z axis of that row of the array.  So index 101 would have rows 0-100, index 102 would have rows 0-101 and so on.

Comment: Show us what you want with a small case, e.g. 3x3.  It may be best if you use lists, not numpy array.  Your misuse of `np.append` suggests that you are already familiar with list append.  Use that.

Comment: I could be presenting the question incorrectly.  I am being given a 2D numpy array, and need to convert it to a 3D numpy array for time series analysis because that is what the method I am feeding it into requires.  The 3D array should have an iteration of snapshots of the previous array on an iterative basis. I will add an example of what I am looking for in the question.

Comment: First: `Z[i]` is equivalent to `my_array[:i]`. Second: your type of array cannot be a 3D numpy array because every "layer" has different dimensions. Did you want something like this, however? `[ my_array[:i] for i in range(100)]` Third: I don't get why you need to copy data redundantly, can't you avoid this?